# Select text between certain characters regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Let's say I have the following string(s):

```
1: /kb/tags/racing?&foo=bar
2: /kb/tags/racing 
3: /kb/tags/racing#hash
4: /kb/tags/racing:foo:bar#hash
5: /kb/tags/racing?&foo=bar#hash
```

Matches:

```
1: Should match "racing"
2: Should match "racing"
3: Should match "racing"
4: Should match "racing:foo:bar"
5: Should match "racing"
```

Here's what I've tried (&failed):

```
/(?<=[kb\/tags])[^\?|\#]*(?=})/
```

This doesn't work what so ever... But I had a dig, any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: What do you want to match/ exclude exactly? (As a sidenote, the `&` char is often not used for the first URL parameter, rather the subsequent ones)

Comment: I put the result/ match in the description next to the url/pathnames @Tyblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
\/kb\/tags.*/([^/?#\s]+)(?!.*\/)
```

And retrieve the matches from capture Group 1.

In the demo, see the [Group 1 captures](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/19) in the right pane.

**Sample JavaScript:**

```
var myregex = /\/kb\/tags.*\/([^\/?#\s]+)(?!.*\/)/;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    thematch = matchArray[1];
} else {
    thematch = "";
}
```

**Explanation**

- `\/kb\/tags` matches `/kb/tags`
- `.*` matches any chars
- `/` matches a forward slash
- The parentheses around `([^/?#\s]+)` capture one or more chars that are not those inside the brackets to Group 1
- The negative lookahead `(?!.*/)` asserts that what follows is not anychars then a forward slash, ensuring we got the last one.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: It's almost there! It splits the match on colons, however it should also match these and the strings after it until it hits a hash or a ?

Comment: Thankyou for such a fast response, how can I also strip the first slash as I don't need that either? I also do need to match based on the `kb/tags/` string specifically too

Comment: The first slash IS stripped because the code I gave you matches Group 1, which is what is inside the parentheses (it does not include the slash). On the demo, in the right pane, you can also see that the slash is not there. :)

Comment: Ahh okay, I see, however `/kb/foo/car:dog:fish#hash` shouldn't match, which is why I was trying to include the `/kb/tags/` string specifically

Comment: Is this the correct way? `\/kb\/tags\/([^?#\s]+)(?!.*\/)` it seems to work :)

Comment: `Is this the correct way?` Yes. If there is nothing between `/kb/tags/` and `racing`, that is correct, and you can remove the `.*` from my last version—which was built to allow for `kb/tags/unwanted/racing...`

Comment: First of all, thankyou for all your help, however, in javascript DEMO `http://jsfiddle.net/R2x92/` It still returns the string `/kb/tags/` I just need the stuff between it, can we fix this with the regex? Or do we need to do a `replace('/kb/tags', '')` on the match?

Comment: The regex is definitely right. Your code is not returning Group 1, as I have mentioned before we need Group 1, not the entire match. Can you please try the code I gave you?

Comment: The key is `thematch = matchArray[1];` This is Group 1.

Comment: For instance look at the output of this [JavaScript demo](http://js.do/code/40985).

Comment: If this were not JavaScript we would not have to use a CAPTURE to Group 1, we could match it directly using `\K` or a lookbehind, but JS regex does not support those. This is the only way in JS, unless you want to install an alternate library (XRegexP). Please try my code and the running [JavaScript demo](http://js.do/code/40985) and let me know if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted

```
(str.match(/(?<=kb\/tags\/)[^?#]*/) || [])[0]
```

But JS doesn't support lookbehinds. Then, you can try a capturing group:

```
(str.match(/kb\/tags\/([^?#]*)/) || [])[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, assuming your hrefs will be like in your examples.

Javascript

```
var hrefs = [
    '/kb/tags/racing?&foo=bar',
    '/kb/tags/racing',
    '/kb/tags/racing#hash',
    '/kb/tags/racing:foo:bar#hash',
    '/kb/tags/racing?&foo=bar#hash',
    'http://example.com/kb/tags/breeding:racing:breeding:all+articles?&sdff=sfff#jsdf'
];

hrefs.forEach(function (href) {
    console.log(href.split('#').shift().split('?').shift().split('/kb/tags/').pop());
});
```

Output

```
racing
racing
racing
racing:foo:bar
racing
breeding:racing:breeding:all+articles
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7NcRw/)

Comment: While this may work, it's definitely not a nice solution, but thankyou anyway

Comment: Of interest: Why is it not nice?

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\/\K(?:[^?#]|$|\n)*
```

Try this